# Execute a stored procedure if else conditions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to know how to execute a stored procedure based on if customer id exists, create a Customer Order for the specified customer. Else, create a new customer with the specified id.

I have some codes here however im getting an error, it says "Procedure or function 'CustOrder1' expects parameter '@custid1', which was not supplied".
 Any help would be good, thanks in advance.

```
declare @custid1 char (6), @CustName1 nvarchar(255)
set @custid1 = 001
set @custName1 = 'Pete'
select @custid1 = 'c102', @custName1 = 'Pete'

update CustomerRecord
    set CustomerID = @custid1
where CustName = @CustName1

select * from CustomerRecord where CustomerID = @custid1
if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    print 'The id ' + cast(@custid1 as  varchar(5)) + ' does not exists'
else
    print 'Update successsful'
go

alter procedure CustOrder1
  @custid1 CHAR (6), @custName1 VARCHAR (40), @SalesOrderID CHAR (10)
as
begin
  if not exists (select * from CustomerRecord
    where CustName = @CustName1)
  begin
    insert into CustomerRecord (CustomerID)
      values (@custid1)
  end
end
go

exec CustOrder1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the procedure CustOrder1 with 3 parameters.

- @custid1
- @custName1
- @SalesOrderID

When you try to execute this procedure without passing any parameters, you will get an error.

Also, the parameter @SalesOrderID is not used in this procedure so could be removed (unless you have only posted part of it).

It also doesn't insert the @custName1 into the CustomerRecord table, so every time this procedure runs it will try to create a new record for that @custid1.

To give a general answer to your question, you are along the right lines. You would need something like (pseudocode to illustrate the structure):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CustOrder
    -- Parameters
AS

BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CustomerRecord WHERE CustName = @custName1)
    BEGIN

        -- Create the customer record.

    END

    -- Create the order.

END
```

Comment: '@SalesOrderID' is the output in which should be created if customer id exists however im not sure what is the syntax of it

Comment: There are several ways you could do it, e.g., use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after your `INSERT` statement (if SalesOrderID is a `PRIMARY KEY`), or you could look into defining it as an `OUTPUT` parameter in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way... for more information, you can visit this [link](https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/search/label/Stored%20Procedure)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CustOrder
@custName1 VARCHAR(50) = '',
@ReturnValue VARCHAR(100) OUT 
AS

BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomerRecord WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE CustName = @custName1)
        BEGIN


          SET @ReturnValue =  -1 -- for customer already exists

        END
   ELSE
        BEGIN

     -- write your insert statement

          SET @ReturnValue =  @@IDENTITY -- for return inserted customer identity column from CustomerRecord 

        END

END
```

Comment: Is it like...  insert into CustomerRecord Values (-@custid1, -@custName1, -@address, -@phone, -@email) or do i insert later at execute procedure.. exec CustOrder2 'c055', 'Denise', '15 Sunway Wk', '93359991', 'denise@a.com'

Comment: You have to write insert query in `ELSE` part, where I also maintained `write your insert statement` as a comment.

In IF condition we are checking the same customer record are already exist or not, if it already exists then simply we set out output parameter which is @ReturnValue =  -1 that means the customer is existing and we no need to insert.

If you still have any confusion then you can contact me.